# regex with string_view returns garbage

Tags: c++, regex, c++17

Matching a regex on a `std::string_view` works fine. But when I return matched substrings, they die for some reason. `std::string_view` argument is being destroyed upon the end of the function's scope, but the memory it points to is valid.
I expected `std::match_results` to point to the initial array and not to make any copies, but the behavior I observe shows that I am wrong.
Is it possible to make this function work without additional allocations for substrings?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <regex>
#include <string_view>

#include <iostream>

using configuration_str = std::string_view;
using platform_str = std::string_view;

std::tuple<configuration_str, platform_str> parse_condition_str(std::string_view conditionValue)
{
    // TODO: fix regex
    constexpr const auto &regexStr =
        R"((?:\'\$\(Configuration\)\s*\|\s*\$\(Platform\)\s*\'==\'\s*)(.+)\|(.+)')";
    static std::regex regex{ regexStr };

    std::match_results<typename decltype(conditionValue)::const_iterator> matchResults{};
    bool matched =
        std::regex_match(conditionValue.cbegin(), conditionValue.cend(), matchResults, regex);

    (void)matched;

    std::string_view config = matchResults[1].str();
    std::string_view platform = matchResults[2].str();

    return { config, platform };
}

int main()
{
    const auto &stringLiteralThatIsALIVE = "'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'";
    const auto&[config, platform] = parse_condition_str(stringLiteralThatIsALIVE);
    std::cout << "config: " << config << "\nplatform: " << platform << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TeYMnn56z

---

CLang-tydy shows a warning: *Object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full expression*
`std::string_view platform = matchResults[2].str();`

Comment: *but the memory it points to is valid.* -- A *view* is just that, just a view.  The `std::string` you are viewing is gone at the end of the function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no, it is not. There is no `std::string`, there's a view to a string literal (in the example). In the actual code it points to a `std::string` that is alive when `parse_condition_str` returns

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I updated the code for more clarity. The orifinal string is alive and will be alive until the end of main. And the string literal will be alive until the end of the program

Comment: `matchResults[1].str();` -- Does this return a view or a separate string object?  It returns a `std::string_type` not a view, in other words a whole different object that represents the data.

Comment: For example, let's look at `std::string_view config = matchResults[1].str();`. Here, `matchResults` is of type `std::match_results<…>`, and `[1]` is its `operator []`, which returns a `std::sub_match`. But then, its `.str()` is returning a `std::basic_string`, see [`std::sub_match<…>::str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match/str). This returned sting will be destroyed at the end of the `parse_condition_str()` function.

Comment: *There is no std::string* -- There is a `std::string`, all hidden by the return of `str()`.

Comment: @heapunderrun big thanks. The brief description on `str()` is ambiguous: *returns the sequence of characters for the particular sub-match*. You can post this explanation as an answer which I will gladly accept. I expected `sub_match` to have a deduced specification from specified `iterator` for `std::match_results`

Comment: The `string_type` indicates this is a different object, not a view.  As a matter of fact, in the Visual C++ implementation, this is `basic_string<char_type>`.

Comment: Where is there a riddle?  The `str()` returns a `std::string (or std::wstring)` (aliased by basic_string<char_type>).  I would have thought this would be obvious.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well imagine that some people may miss some things. For example, `std::match_results` specialization for `std::string` will not compile for `std::string_view`, hence you need to specialize it for view's iterator type. You *expect* derived subtypes to behave consistently. And a brief description for `str()` on cppreference says *returns the sequence of characters for the particular sub-match*, which does not imply `std::basic_string` - you have to open the page and find out it explicitly. And constructing `std::string_view` did not fire any warnings.

Comment: Well, the next step is to figure out what the return types indicate in cppreference.  Seeing `std::string_type` as a return type indicates it is an object (of some type), not a reference to an existing entity, not a pointer, and if it were an iterator, cppreference is consistent in their description to say "iterator" in all other classes I am aware of.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this is true. But all that I am saying is that pointing out that `str()` returns  `std::basic_string` would solve the initial problem very fast. If this was "so obvious" I wouldn't spend time on asking a question...

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I sympathise, but there's an important takeaway here.  Many STL functions return an object by value, and if you use that object directly to initialise something non-owning (a `string_view` being a case in point) then it won't end well.  `string_view`s are slippery customers, they're often not worth the minor optimisations they bring.

Comment: @PaulSanders well the whole variety of `std::match_results` member functions work with underlying array, not making any copies. `std::string_view::substr` doe not return a newly allocated `std::basic_string`, why the difference with `std::sub_match` then? Standard regex is not the fastest thing, so why add implicit allocations for "substrings"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, let's look at the following line:

```cpp
std::string_view config = matchResults[1].str();
```

Here, `matchResults` is of type [`std::match_results`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results), and `[1]` is its [`std::match_results::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at), which returns an [`std::sub_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match).

But then, `.str()` is its [`std::sub_match::str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match/str), which returns an `std::basic_string`.

This returned temporary sting object will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression (thanks, @BenVoigt, for the correction), i.e., in this case, immediately after the `config` gets initialized and the line in question finishes executing. So, the Clang's warning you quote is correct.

By the time when the `parse_condition_str()` function returns, both the `config` and `platform` string-views will thus be pointing into already destroyed strings.

Comment: "will be destroyed at the end of the `parse_condition_str()` function"  Won't they be destroyed at the end of the full-expression?  Or is this an example of the C++20 exhanced rules for lifetime extension of temporaries?  (Before C++20, an argument to a converting constructor could never have its lifetime extended)

Comment: Also the "tidy" warning quoted in the question thinks it is the full expression.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're right, I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Manually specifying pointer with offset and length yields the desirable results:

```
std::string_view config{conditionValue.data() + matchResults.position(1), matchResults.length(1)};
std::string_view platform{conditionValue.data() + matchResults.position(2), matchResults.length(2)};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cGjs39Ehq

<strike>However the question still stands in regards to why `.str()` method on a submatch returns a temporary and results in garbage.</strike>